# How to do arp spoofing on the virtual machine? (Against host)

Tags: kali-linux, arp-spoofing

I have an Ubuntu host and a Kali guest, I want to do spoofing over the host network but when I tried to do spoofing it recognizes only the network between guests.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSLstrip is not working in the local network](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112878/sslstrip-is-not-working-in-the-local-network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your VM settings to ensure that the guest OS is running in 'bridged' network mode rather than NAT (may be called a 'virtual network') or host only. NAT will mess up layer 2 traffic due to not being on the same network segment. Host only will only allow communication with other guests.

The simplest way to do lots of tasks involving layer 2 traffic is often to obtain a USB Ethernet adapter and mount it as a removable device in the guest OS. These are widely available and commonly used to connect ultrabooks without Ethernet ports to wired networks.

The guest OS is then directly connected to its own NIC and you do not have to worry about what the host OS and virtualisation software are doing to your traffic or the interface and any resultant interference. This works awesome for VLAN hopping too.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that is because your Kali machine in on "host-only" mode.

Have you configured the guest machine to be on "bridge " mode ?
This way, both your machines will be on the same network.
And the attack should work.
However,be aware that preforming the attack on virtual machine may effect the attack(specially when you preform ARP spoofing and DNS hijacking  with ettercap)